# Salt: Condition based on systemd being available or not

Tags: salt-stack, systemd

I want to install this file via salt-stack.

```
# /etc/logrotate.d/foo

/home/foo/log/foo.log {
    compress
    # ...
    postrotate
      systemctl restart foo.service
    endscript
}
```

Unfortunately there are some old machines which don't have systemd yet.

For those machines I need this postrotate script:

```
/etc/init.d/foo restart
```

How to get this done in salt?

I guess I need something like this:

```
postrotate
 {% if ??? %}
   /etc/init.d/foo restart
 {% else %}
   systemctl restart foo.service
 {% endif %} 
endscript
```

But how to implement `???` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can discover this by taking advantage of the `service` module, which is a virtual module that is ultimately implemented by the specific module appropriate for the machine.

From the command line we can discover the specific module being used with [`test.provider`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.test.html#salt.modules.test.provider).  Here is an example:

```
$ sudo salt 'some.*' test.provider service
some.debian.8.machine:
    systemd
some.debian.7.machine:
    debian_service
some.redhat.5.machine:
    rh_service
```

To discover this in a template we can use:

```
{{ salt["test.provider"]("service") }}
```

So, you could use something like:

```
postrotate
  {% if salt["test.provider"]("service") != "systemd" %}
   /etc/init.d/foo restart
 {% else %}
   systemctl restart foo.service
 {% endif %} 
endscript
```

#### NOTE:

The possible return value of `test.provider` will vary across platform.  From the source, these appear to be the currently available providers:

```
$ cd salt/modules && grep -l "__virtualname__ = 'service'" *.py
debian_service.py
freebsdservice.py
gentoo_service.py
launchctl.py
netbsdservice.py
openbsdrcctl.py
openbsdservice.py
rest_service.py
rh_service.py
smf.py
systemd.py
upstart.py
win_service.py
```

Comment: Thank you, just for the records, here is a link to the docs of "test.provider": https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.test.html#salt.modules.test.provider It returns "rh_service" for system5 (/etc/init.d/) init systems.

Comment: @guettli `rh_service` is probably specific to redhat init systems.  On debian for example, it will return `debian_service` for init based systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just call out directly to Salt's `service` module which will do the right thing based on the OS.

```
postrotate
  salt-call service.restart foo
endscript
```

A more "salty" way of doing this would be something like this:

```
my_file:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://logrotate.d/foo
    - name: /etc/logrotate.d/foo
    - watch_in:
      - service: my_foo_service

my_foo_service:
  service.running:
    - name: foo
```

This will lay down the file for you and then restart the `foo` service if any changes are made.

Comment: I don't get the "more salty" solution. The file `foo.log` is not managed by salt. It is the logfile a third party daemon running on the minion. AFAIK salt does not use or tool like inotify to detect changes. AFAIK it only restarts the service if the file gets changed by salt. It does not detect changes made by hand (for example vi). Are you sure the "more salty" way works?

Comment: @guettli In your question you said you want to "install this file via salt-stack" ... that's simply what the "salty" way Utah_Dave is suggesting actually does.

Comment: @guetti And if you wish to use Salt to monitor (and revert) changes to configuration files made by hand, then have a look at Salt beacons and Salt reactors (but this is outside the scope of this particular question)

Comment: @donkopotamus I updated my question. The line "/home/foo/log/foo.log {" is the first line in the file, not the file name. I hope this is more clear now. The file name is `/etc/logrotate.d/foo`.